# How to put data in a csv file, with python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to put lists of data in a csv file, this is my data

```
list_info  = [('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000200', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000500', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000600', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000700', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000800', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000900', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000a00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '11', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000b00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000c00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '13', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000d00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '14', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000e00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000f00', '0', '0', '0', '23')]
```

This is my code:

```
    print(list_info)
    for row in list_info:
        print (row)
        for column in row:
            out.write(column)
        out.write('\n')
    out.close()
```

But it does not work, it gives me every list concatenated in the same column, like this:

```
155215012502141592cc000000012000000000001000000020000023
```

The expected result is:

```
time      |  ID           |a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n         |o|p|q|r| 
1552150|02141592cc00000001|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0000000200|0|0|0|23|
```

Comment: Most proably you have opened the file in binary mode
Can you show your initialisation of `out`

Comment: Why are you not using the `csv` module?

Comment: @AshishGhodake  could you please see the edited question?

Comment: @hansolo  could you please see the edited question?

Comment: @roganjosh  what is the csv module? I don't know it. This is the first time I try to put data a csv file

Comment: @user6594048 I suggest you use the `csv` module for this too. Here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `csv` module,

```
import csv
# your list_info here
header = 'time ID a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r'.split()
with open('some_data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(list_info) # write all the rows at once as suggested by @roganjosh
```

Comment: I wrote that `csv` module would be also a solid solution. Now that I see it, I prefer the my elementary answer. The problem just does not have any complexity about it, making `csv` necessary.

Comment: @mkiever you're right that pandas is overkill, though.

Comment: @mkiever the CSV module is distributed as part of CPython. Unless you're not using CPython (unlikely), you got the dependency anyway

Answer (score 0):

use `csv` package:

```
import csv

list_info  = [('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000200', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000500', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000600', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000700', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000800', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000900', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000a00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '11', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000b00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000c00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '13', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000d00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '14', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000e00', '0', '0', '0', '23'), ('1552150125', '02141592cc00000001', '15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0000000f00', '0', '0', '0', '23')]

h = 'time ID a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r'.split()

with open('file.csv', 'w',newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerow(h)
    wr.writerows(list_info)
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution with elementary Python tools.
Using `csv` module of the standard library would be also a solid solution. This just uses `str.format`. Note, that I advise to always use an encoding when opening files.

```
out = open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
for row in list_info:
        out.write('|'.join(row))
        out.write('\n')
out.close()
```